Does this tensor identity hold in any kind of generality?
Assuming Minkowski spacetime, I am given an antisymmetric tensor $F^{\alpha\beta}$, and am asked to prove the following identity:

$$ F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} = -F_{\mu\alpha,\beta}F^{\alpha\beta} \tag{1}$$

Here's the beginning of my attempt:
\begin{align*}
F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} &= \left(g^{\lambda\alpha} F_{\mu\lambda}\right)_{,\nu}\ g_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma} 
\\&= g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F_{\mu\lambda}g_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma} +g^{\lambda\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma}
\\&= g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda}F^{\nu\sigma} +\delta^{\lambda}_{\sigma}F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}F^{\nu\sigma}
\\&= g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda}F^{\nu\sigma} +F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}F^{\nu\lambda}
\end{align*}
Now at this point it becomes clear, that the second term on the right is what I should be left with if I am to prove this. The only missing steps would then be to use the anti-symmetry of $F$, and a renaming of dummy indices.
So, what I am unsure about is whether the first term $g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda}F^{\nu\sigma}$ actually vanishes generally in flat spacetime. Am I expected to conclude that since it vanishes when taking the constant metric, i.e for the specific coordinate choice $\eta_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}$, then it vanishes in general?
Such an assumption doesn't seem to make sense, as I know that $(1)$ can't be a tensor identity if it is tied to a specific choice of coordinates. On the other hand, I tried to use the various symmetries that the left term has but I came up with nothing to imply it vanishes identically.
I suspect I am missing something because it is obvious I should use the assumption of flat spacetime somehow, but it's clearly not by taking the constant Minkowski metric as a specific choice, is it?
The other alternative is that there's an error in the exercise and it should have specified I have to assume the choice of a constant metric. But that would in fact also be weird, as it makes this identity highly specialized (at least I don't think we would call it a true tensor identity). Is there an error in the exercise, or am I missing something else entirely here?

The partial derivative of a tensor is not a tensor anyway, so there is no reason to expect this relation to be covariant.

@Gaussian97 Well, the covariant derivative is a sum of partial derivatives. (recall that the Christoffel symbol is a sum of metric partial derivatives essentially, too..). So here we have in fact a sum of such partial derivatives that is supposedly $=0$. I don't think it is impossible then that such an identity may hold generally.

You said Minkovski spacetime. Therefore I'd expect the partial derivative $g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}$ to be zero.

@Amit, This is of course a possibility, and for a more complicated relation you should totally consider it, but here I don't think you can save it, at least not for a general tensor T. But basically proving that this expression is indeed a tensor is exactly proving that the extra term you get is zero.

@KurtG. I don't think that's right. See for example This Phys.SE question. If it were that simple to distinguish flat from curved spacetime, we wouldn't need for example the Riemann tensor to do that.

Minkovski space time has the metric diag$(-1,1,1,1)$ in the standard coordinates $t,x,y,z,.$ If you want to make your life harder and do it in spherical coordinates where the components of the metric are no longer constant please go ahead.

@KurtG. I know that the identity holds for the choice of a constant metric, and have stated so in the question. The whole crux of the question is to ask whether this is really a tensor identity or not, and if not, what is actually the point of such an exercise/proof...

As @Gaussian97 has already correctly pointed out: it is not a tensor identity when the Christoffel symbols are not zero. This happens when you choose "wrong" coordinates, even in flat space time. This being said: when you write $F_\mu{}^\alpha{}{\color{red};,\nu}$ and so on it will be a tensor identity. Then you can use metric compatibility of the Levi-Civita connection which boils down to $g^{\lambda\alpha}{}{\color{red};,\nu}=0,.$

@KurtG. oh, interesting. I don't see why that is true, but if the identity holds with the covariant derivative in generally curved spacetime, I thought that would imply replacing $\nabla \rightarrow \partial$ would mean it holds in flat spacetime. But I'm not sure about this latter statement...

Oh, I see now, we can do $\nabla \rightarrow \partial$, only if we choose a constant metric. Regardless of curved/flat spacetime. So ignore my last comment. It seems then at the moment I am forced to conclude this exercise is implicitly asking to assume a constant metric, or otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Yes. I think so. A good book to learn those things from is S. Carroll, Spacetime and Geometry of which is a free preprint in arXiv (Lecture Notes on General Relativity).

I think I have figured out why it is enough to prove the identity for coordinates with a constant metric $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}$.
We can start by noting that both sides of the identity to be proven, are a pair of covariant vectors:
$$\underbrace{F_{\color{red}{\mu}}{}^{\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha}}_{\large A_\mu} = \underbrace{-F_{\color{red}\mu\alpha,\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}}_{\large B_\mu}\ ,$$
where I've marked in red the index $\mu$, the only free index, to demonstrate that is indeed the case.
However, very importantly, this only holds if we assume a constant metric! To see why, note that due to the partial derivatives, neither side of the equation transforms as a tensor, in generally curvilinear coordinates:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}}{\partial{x^\nu}}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} &= \frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\frac{\partial }{\partial{x^{\nu{'}}}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x^{\alpha{'}}} F_{\mu{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}\right)\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\rho'} }\frac{\partial x^{\sigma'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}F^{\rho'}{}_{\sigma'}
\\&=\delta^{\nu'}_{\rho'} \frac{\partial }{\partial{x^{\nu{'}}}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x^{\alpha{'}}} F_{{\mu}{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}\right)\frac{\partial x^{\sigma'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}F^{\rho'}{}_{\sigma'}
\\&=\left(\frac{\partial^2 x^{{\mu}{'}}}{\partial x^\mu\partial x^{\nu'}} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x^{\alpha{'}}} F_{{\mu}{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}+\frac{\partial x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial^2 x^\alpha}{\partial x^{\alpha{'}}\partial x^{\nu'}} F_{{\mu}{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}+\frac{\partial x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x^{\alpha{'}}} \frac{\partial F_{{\mu}{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}}{\partial x^{\nu'}}\right)\frac{\partial x^{\sigma'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}F^{\nu'}{}_{\sigma'}
\\&=\left(\delta^{\sigma'}_{\alpha'}\frac{\partial^2 x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu\partial x^{\nu'}}  +\frac{\partial x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial^2 x^\alpha}{\partial x^{\alpha{'}}\partial x^{\nu'}} \frac{\partial x^{\sigma'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right)F_{{\mu}{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}F^{\nu'}{}_{\sigma'}+\delta^{\sigma'}_{\alpha'} \frac{\partial x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial F_{{\mu}{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}}{\partial x^{\nu'}}F^{\nu'}{}_{\sigma'}
\\&=\underbrace{\left(\delta^{\sigma'}_{\alpha'}\frac{\partial^2 x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu\partial x^{\nu'}}  +\frac{\partial x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial^2 x^\alpha}{\partial x^{\alpha{'}}\partial x^{\nu'}} \frac{\partial x^{\sigma'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right)F_{{\mu}{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}F^{\nu'}{}_{\sigma'}}_{\large\text{"Non-tensorial"}}+\underbrace{ \frac{\partial x^{\mu{'}}}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial F_{{\mu}{'}}{}^{\alpha{'}}}{\partial x^{\nu'}}F^{\nu'}{}_{\alpha'}}_{\large\text{"Tensorial"}}
\end{align*}
What we see from the above, is that writing the expression as one transformed from different (primed) coordinates, we get two terms: the first one is clearly non-tensorial, as it involves second order partial derivatives, that involve not only the index $\mu$. This is due to the ordinary partial derivative in the original expression, taken with respect to  the second rank tensor $F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}$.
The second part however, is clearly tensorial and what would have alone existed, if the expression was a proper tensor. Namely, a single contraction with the Jacobian of the transformation, $\large\frac{\partial x^{\mu\normalsize '}}{\partial x^{\mu} }$ that we have to carry out, to relate the object (which would have really been a co-vector then) in the primed frame, to the unprimed one.
Therefore, we see that the mere existence of an explicit ordinary partial derivative in the expression, implies it can't be a tensor. So, to salvage any kind of sense out of this exercise, I must assume that in fact it is a tensor, and what I am seeing is a special case of the covariant derivative, taken in coordinates where the metric is constant.
In other words, since we know that when the metric is constant, all Christoffel symbols vanish, so that we clearly have:
$$ F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}{}_{;\nu} = F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}{}_{,\nu} $$
Therefore, if we want to prove this identity explicitly assuming the coordinates are generally curvilinear, we must rewrite it as:
$$ F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}{}_{\color{red}{;}\nu}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} = -F_{\mu\alpha\color{red}{;}\beta}{}F^{\alpha\beta}$$
Which would make the proof also rather simple, because as noted in the comments, from the definition of the metric we have $g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{;\nu}=0$.
So, granting all that, if we now accept that the exercise is phrased assuming a constant metric, we have no problem seeing that we are asked to prove an identity of the form:
$$ A_\mu = B_\mu $$
So, proceeding as in my original post above, but now being clearly aware that we are forced to take $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}$, we find that indeed the equality for that choice of coordinates holds.
Now, as already discussed, in general coordinates, partial derivatives become covariant derivatives ($\partial \rightarrow \nabla$), both sides of the identity remain proper tensors (co-vectors in that case), so that we know they transform via a contraction with the Jacobian of the transformation:
$$ A_{\mu'} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial{x^{{\mu}{'}}}}A_\mu = x^{\mu}_{,\mu'}A_\mu $$
$$ B_{\mu'} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial{x^{\mu{'}}}}B_\mu = x^{\mu}_{,\mu'}B_\mu $$
From which we immediately see that our proof in the "special" coordinates where we have shown that $A_\mu = B_\mu$, implies the identity is true in arbitrary coordinates, $A_{\mu{'}} = B_{\mu{'}}$.
